# Delphi auto scroll through combobox

Tags: delphi

I would like to know if there is a way to auto increment or scroll through a combobox.

For example every 30 seconds I want it to choose the next option in the combobox continuously until it gets to the last value, then it must go back to index 0 and continue from there.

The reason for this is that each value in my combobox contains a value that calls data from the database to display, as these screens will be unmanned I want the to automatically change without user input.

I added a timer and the following code and set the interval as advised below (30000)

```
procedure TForm3.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
if ComboBox1.Index < comboBox1.Index.MaxValue then
ComboBox1.Index := +1
else
ComboBox1.Index := 0;
end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increment Itemindex until Itemindex = Count - 1, then set Itemindex to 0.

```
Procedure IncLoopCombobox(CB: TComboBox);
begin
  if CB.ItemIndex < CB.Items.Count - 1 then
    CB.ItemIndex := CB.ItemIndex + 1
  else
    CB.ItemIndex := 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

From a timer with `Interval` property set to 30000 ms I would use this code in its `OnTimer` tick event. For this code you must have at least one item in combo box:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := (ComboBox1.ItemIndex + 1) mod ComboBox1.Items.Count;
end;
```

Comment: +1 Nice to see you answering in answers rather than comments!

Comment: I don't quite understand the concept here, please elaborate on the mod part.

Comment: @Silentdarkness The documentation explains it: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: Assume you have 2 items in your combo box (`Items.Count = 2`) and you're on the first item with index 0 (`ItemIndex = 0`). Then the result of this statement will be `(0 + 1) mod 2` which gives you 1, because the remainder from dividing of 1 by 2 is 1. This will move you to the next item (`ItemIndex = 1`) with calculation of `(1 + 1) mod 2` which moves you to the first item, because the remainder from dividing of 2 by 2 is 0. @David, thanks!

Comment: ok interesting concept but mod wont work properly depending on the amount of indexes you have due to mathematical calculations.

Comment: say I have 30 indexes. and im on position 27, 27/30 = 0.9, It will move me to position 9

Comment: No, if you'll be on the index 27 (`ItemIndex = 27`) from 30 items (`Items.Count = 30`), it will give you `(27 + 1) mod 30` which [`is 28`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2827+%2B+1%29+mod+30). Take that as an integer division, where if you divide 27 by 30, it will give you 0 and 27 remain. For the theory of `mod` operator you can look for instance at [`this article`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). The only weakness of this one liner is that you can't have `Items.Count = 0`, otherwise you'd be dividing by 0.

Comment: @Silentdarkness You don't understand division remainders. The code in this answer is accurate.